Unstable speeds and crashes when downloading torrents to external hard drive
I have an issue, maybe someone here experienced it and can help. I have a laptop with newly installed Ubuntu 24.04 (Adding a screenshot of my specs)
[]
This laptop is mainly used for media server (plex and stuff), and I recently got WD my book 12TB for that. I connected the drive to the laptop and tried to download torrents (from torrentleech) to it using transmission, ktorrent and qbittorrent. When I used transmission, the download speeds were really inconsistent (it showed 20MB/s and then 0, and back and forth). When I used ktorrent or qbittorrent, on both the client crashed. When I changed the destination directory to the internal ssd, everything worked perfectly.
I suspected that the issue is due to the fact that torrents have many peers and download few files simultaneously, and by the nature of hard drive, inconsistencies makes sense. to check that I connected the external hard drive to my windows laptop and tried to download the same torrent (using qbittorrent), and from that laptop it worked perfectly, which means its not a hardware limitation (at least not in the hard drive). I also read somewhere that windows by default limits the number of active connections allowed, so I tried in Ubuntu to limit the numbers of allowed peers to 4, but still the same issue remained.
I will add that when I copy files to the external hard drive (either from windows or ubuntu), the write speeds are constantly on 200MB/s
Has anyone encountered this issue? maybe someone have any advise? I tried to look over the internet with no luck...
Thank you in advance!

Time outs and USB issues are the cause. Only different hardware will fix this. Your computer and the hard drive USB.
